# FutureProvider using .whenData() shorthand

Tags: flutter, riverpod

Riverpod provides a shorthand using .whenData() where you do not need to supply loading and error parameters. But I can't find example of how this code can be used to return widget in build() function.

```
     Widget build(BuildContext context, ScopedReader watch) {
          final cityListFuture = watch(cityListFutureProvider);
          // This one is working fine
          return cityListFuture.when(
              data: (value) {
                return Text("Data goes here");
              },
              loading: () => CircularProgressIndicator(),
              error: (error, stack) {
                return Container();
              });
     
          // This is shorthand for .when() without the need of loading and error
          // ERROR: The return type 'AsyncValue<Text>' isn't a 'Widget', as required by the closure's context.
          return cityListFuture.whenData((value) => Text("Data goes here"));
     }
```

Anyone knows how can we use .whenData() to return a widget?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite an interesting documentation I had to go through for this.

It seems like the `whenData` is probably not exactly what is sounds like it should do.

Because all it does is that it return an `AsyncValue<Widget>` instead of directly returning `Widget` like the `when` function does.

So one way to use it would be,

```
return cityListFuture.whenData((val) => Text(val)).data!.value;
```

Here, the `value` would be your `Text(value)` itself.

One thing to be careful of here is the `!` symbol since the `data` can be null. So you would have to manually have `if` checks.

Other thing to note here is that, you might as well achieve the same thing with something like this,

```
return Text(watch(cityListFutureProvider).data?.value);
```

Assumptions have been made that your `value` is a String.

Comment: Was this something you were looking for ?

Comment: Thanks Nisanth, whenData().data.value works! Considering whenData() was released in 0.3.0 about a year ago, and this is still not fully implemented kind of surprised me. Anyway thanks for your help, I've accepted this as answer.

Comment: No, thank you for letting me answer. Going through their source code was quite fun. :D I am learning Flutter and it's good.

Comment: I've started learning Flutter for more than a year now, and made several small apps along the way, I have to say it's the most enjoyable mobile framework I've used so far, never look back at jQueryMobile, PhoneGap, Meteor, Ionic, Xamarin again! Do you use state management for Flutter? what's your preferred solution?

Comment: Definitely Agreed. I was using `react-native` earlier but had way too many performance issues. Flutter is much better at handling them. Unfortunately, I have not encountered state management yet. I am still about to study on them. But from what I understand, the `Provider` pattern solves most of the use cases.

Comment: "this is still not fully implemented"  It is completely implemented as designed.  https://pub.dev/documentation/riverpod/latest/riverpod/AsyncValue/data.html

Comment: @RandalSchwartz Agreed. My terminology was more towards the point that the design wasn't as intuitive as it sounds. Thanks for pointing out, edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Now it is `return cityListFuture.whenData((val) => Text(val)).asData!.value;`

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**